# train gpt-2 modal with json data

Tags: python, training-data, gpt-3, gpt-2

I have a dataset in JSON format that contains questions, options, categories, and correct answers. I would like to train a GPT-2 model on this dataset, but I am getting an error.

i got following error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'Dataset' from 'transformers'"

I have written the following code:

```
import json
import random
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, Dataset

def convert_json_to_text(json_data):
 

  text = ''
  for question_and_answers in json_data: 
    random.shuffle(question_and_answers['answers'])
 
    text += f"{question_and_answers['category']}: {question_and_answers['question']}\n"
 
    for option in question_and_answers['answers']:
      text += f"- {option}\n"
 
    text += f"Correct Answer: {question_and_answers['correct_answer']}\n\n"

  return text
 
with open("questions.json", "r") as f:
  json_data = json.load(f)
 
text = convert_json_to_text(json_data)
 
train_dataset = Dataset.from_text(text)
 
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2")
model.train()
for epoch in range(10):
  for batch in train_dataset:
    loss = model(input_ids=batch['input_ids'], labels=batch['input_ids'])
    loss.backward()
    model.optimizer.step()
    model.optimizer.zero_grad()
 
model.save_pretrained("gpt2_model.pt")
```

Here is sample dataset:

```
[
  {
    "question": "Q1. Which operator returns true if the two compared values are not equal?",
    "category": "javascript",
    "answers": [" <>", " ~", " ==!", " !=="],
    "correct_answer": " !=="
  },
  {
    "question": "Q2. How is a forEach statement different from a for statement?",
    "category": "javascript",
    "answers": [
      " Only a for statement uses a callback function.",
      " A for statement is generic, but a forEach statement can be used only with an array.",
      " Only a forEach statement lets you specify your own iterator.",
      " A forEach statement is generic, but a for statement can be used only with an array."
    ],
    "correct_answer": " A for statement is generic, but a forEach statement can be used only with an array."
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your issue is that you are trying to load Datasets from the Transformers library, but Datasets is actually it's own [library](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.14.5/how_to). The `.from_text` [method](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.from_text) you are using though is for text files though, I would recommend looking through this [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.14.5/loading) to see if one of these methods would work better for you. I think reformatting the json you already have might be the easiest way for you to move forward.